# unable to access zend views from controller file

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-controller, zend-layout

I am able to print the form content in the controller file, but when I assign the form view as `$this->view->form = $form` and trying to display the form design using `echo $this->form` in `login.phtml` file, form design is not viewed, instead displaying blank page....

What could be the issue ??

Comment: well in your `application.ini` file set display error to 1 and see if you get any error

Comment: @experimentX.. I have set display errors to 1 but see no errors.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it should work:

```
// in the controller
$this->view->form = $form;

// in the view
<?= $this->form ?>
```

So the problem is somewhere else.

The blank page is displayed probably due to that the `error_reporting` is turrned off.

Update `application.ini` and set `error_reporting`, displaying errors and throwing exceptions to `true` to see what is actually happening.

#### Edit:

Things to check:

- Is your view initialized?
- Does your `application.ini` contains any `resources.view[]=`
- haven't you accidentally overwritten the view? `$this->view = null`

Comment: My statement is   $this->view->form = $form; and I am getting the following error message....   Strict Standards:  Creating default object from empty value in C:\dev\workspaces\adxweb\application\adxsearch\modules\account\controllers\AuthController.php on line 81

Comment: @lakshman So look at that line and spot the problem. Maybe you have disabled view somehow?

Comment: Hmmm....The line holds the following in controller file and it is even displaying the form when I give echo as " echo $this->getView()->form = $form; "  but when remove echo and use the following statement "echo $this->form" in login.phtml file, it is not displaying the form design...I am really not getting any clue how to trace this...plz suggest if any alternate way to get the view...ty

Comment: @lakshman use `Zend_Debug::dump($this->view)` before the line and the line before and so on, until you will get the real view object dumped instead of null.

Comment: plz see my code...I have edited ur response and added to it...thanks for your help

Comment: The problem is with $this->view...I have tried to display static message by assigning in controller file as "$this->view->pageTitle = "User Registration Form";" and given as "<h2><?php echo $this->pageTitle ;?></h2>" in login.phtml and it did not display the message...plz let me know what could be the issue for not getting this displayed...thanx